# Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have a weird problem, I was using a menu.xml file in my android application like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/toc"
        compat:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

and it was working well, but some days ago i was updating my eclipse to the last version, and after that, the app:showAsAction="always" shows the error:

> Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library
>   and after that my action bar icons was moved to the overflow bar and not showing the in the action bar at all.

anyway, the appcompat library is the parent of my base style.
what should I do to resolve that?

Answer (score 19):

You need to do three things-

1. Add these 3 things `xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context="com.example.sample.YourActivity" xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your `<menu>` tag

   along with the usual `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
2. Add `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to your `<item>`.
3. Finally, clean your project via Project -> Clean...

The last step is what solved it for me. Simply cleaning the project (they can get so dirty sometimes)

This is what the final code looks like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.sample.YourActivity"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: I found that all I need to do to remove the error was Project/Clea/myProjName.  However if I edit the xml again the error returns so I have to re-clean.

Comment: Use `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` instead of `xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"`

Answer (score 15):

This works for me i have used appcompatlibrary:

```
compat:showAsAction="always"
```

instead of:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

And to use compat:showAsAction="always" ,
inside menu.xml include the line:

```
<menu   
   ......
  <!-- include the below line -->
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
```

Comment: Thanks, but not the answer, compat is a not recognized namespace for me

Comment: menu.xml file must include... <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

Comment: same error: Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library, it's confusing me, i've rid a lot of documents and all of them talking about adding MyApp namespace as you mentioned, but it does not working for me

Comment: show your full menu.xml and are you using ActionBarActivity or ActionBar only?

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ><item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/toc"
    app:showAsAction="always"/></menu>

Comment: now try all three app:showAsAction="always", compat:showA... android:show...after including xmlns:compat="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto".... it works for me..

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same problem. These two options worked for me:

1.Including - xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" > and then using:"compat:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>"

2.Not including the compat and simply using: app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

PS: Using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library

Issue: Ensures that menu items are using the right namespace
Id: AppCompatResource

When using the appcompat library, menu resources should refer to the showAsAction in the app: namespace, not the android: namespace.

Similarly, when not using the appcompat library, you should be using the android:showAsAction attribute.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/toc"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
        compat:showAsAction="always"/> 
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the following line to your `item` element to suppress the warning. Having the namespace as `compat` vs `app` for `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` doesn't actually do anything special.

`tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"`

full code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/toc"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
        compat:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Note: the `compat` tag could be `app` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my multi-module Gradle project. It was reported by Android Lint CLI.

## Environment of the issue

My modules look like:

[image: My modules]

`feature_home` is an `AppCompat` module, which has a menu like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:title="@string/edit"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I wanted to run Android Lint for the entire application with a single `./gradlew` command, so I added the following lint option to `app/build.gradle`:

```groovy
lintOptions {
    checkDependencies true
}
```

Then, when I run `./gradlew :feature_home:lint`, everything was fine, but when I tried to check all modules via `./gradlew :app:lint`, I had the subject issue: `Error: Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library`.

---

## Solution

The problem was due to my `app` module wasn't `AppCompat`. So adding the `AppCompat` dependency to `app/build.gradle` resolved the issue:

```groovy
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me woks this approach:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/maker_appbar_next"
        android:title="@string/next"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

</menu>
```